# expand grid for an arbitrary number of vectors in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, grid

I want to use expand.grid in R but have it work over two pre-specified vectors and an arbitrary remaining amount:

example, two vectors d and w, and 3 vectors of length 4:

```
M = expand.grid(d = 1:3, w = 1:3, rep(list(1:4),(3)))
```

The problem is that it thinks that the last thing is one object, and I want it to have Var3, Var4, and Var5.  Instead, we get:

```
    M
   d w       Var3
1  1 1 1, 2, 3, 4
2  2 1 1, 2, 3, 4
3  3 1 1, 2, 3, 4
4  1 2 1, 2, 3, 4
5  2 2 1, 2, 3, 4
6  3 2 1, 2, 3, 4
7  1 3 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Interestingly when I do it alone without the first two vectors, it can expandgrid:

```
M = expand.grid(rep(list(1:4),(3)))

     Var1 Var2 Var3
1     1    1    1
2     2    1    1
3     3    1    1
4     4    1    1
5     1    2    1
6     2    2    1
7     3    2    1
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check `?expand.grid` and take a look at the parameters, it says:

> ...
>   vectors, factors or a list containing these.

It doesn't seem like it accepts mixed vectors and lists. Concatenating the vectors and list to make a single list as parameter will work:

```
M = expand.grid(c(list(d = 1:3, w = 1:3), rep(list(1:4), 3)))
M
#    d w Var3 Var4 Var5
#1   1 1    1    1    1
#2   2 1    1    1    1
#3   3 1    1    1    1
#4   1 2    1    1    1
#5   2 2    1    1    1
#6   3 2    1    1    1
# ...
```

Comment: Why do you put d and w into separate lists?

Comment: @AlexR Good point. I don't have to. But that won't affect the result.